# How to create an object from UI elements in a nice way?

Tags: android, design-patterns, software-design

In my android application I have some fields like

```
MyButton a;
MyEditText b;
MySpinner c;
MyTextView d;
```

Each of these is like `public class MyButton extends Button implements InfoExtract` and

```
public interface InfoExtract{
    String getTheText();
}
```

Out of these fields (the user can change some of them), there is a UserProfile to be created like so:

```
public class ProfileUpdate {
    // The fields have to be string no matter what
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String dateOfBirth;
    String relationshipStatus
}
```

The execution flow is like that:

```
List<InfoExtract> uiElements = new ArrayList<InfoExtract>();
uiElements.add(a);
uiElements.add(b);
uiElements.add(c);
uiElements.add(d);
someButton.setOnClickListener(new SaveProfileListener(uiElements);
```

The `SaveProfileListener` more or less does this:

```
ProfileUpdate pup = new ProfileUpdate();
int i = 0;
pup.firstName = uiElements.get(i++).getTheText()
pup.lastName = uiElements.get(i++).getTheText();
pup.dateOfBirth = uiElements.get(i++).getTheText();
pup.relationshipStatus = uiElements.get(i++).getTheText();
```

**Bad thing #1:** If I want to add another fields its obviously much work.

**Bad thing #2:** The order of elements in the list is important.

**Bad thing #3:** I cannot easily manipulate the date format for dateOfBirth for example.

What i could have done but what is equally bad:

```
// Pass the listener what fields it should use.
someButton.setOnClickListener(new SaveProfileListener(a, b, c, d);
```

**How to make this nice and clean?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Map and a new Enum type for each field.